# Should I create a ViewModel in the MainActivity in order to use MutableLiveData with a NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-navigation

I am using Navigation Graph and View Models. I have used ViewModels almost exclusively in Fragments and don't have them in the MainActivity. Now I need to update TextViews in the NavigationDrawer which can be accessed through the MainActivity when the current user profile changes. I wanted to use MutableLiveData, but in [this example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#create_livedata_objects) they have it associated with a ViewModel. In order to implement it this way I need to create a ViewModel for the MainActivity. Is that a common practice?

Comment: Yes, it's normal to do that. Just note that when you create a ViewModel in a Activity, that ViewModel can be shared across all fragment in the Activity (in your case the NavGraph), so use it to store global information and in this case the User information.

Comment: Oh, my God. Thank you. I need a way to share variables across all fragments and have been using a repository which is a wrapper for PreferenceManager. Put this in a response and and after I implement (over the weekend), I will check it as an answer.

Comment: Hope it helps, also refer to the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate for more information and pay attention to the scope of your ViewModel!

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you. I now remember I used this for Fragment to Fragment communication now but I didn't recall that they had an Activity to Fragment communication section. Sometimes it's hard to gauge when to create a ViewModel or not. Certain scenarios are easier (Parent Fragment -> Child Fragment) but when you string them together it gets harder. What if the Parent needs communicate with the Activity. Do you use one ViewModel for all three? And they get more complex from there.

Comment: So in my current case I have a MainActivity with a ViewModel (now) and a DialogFragment with a ViewModel. The DialogFragmentViewModel holds a list of items to select and, once selected, it closes and sets the item in the MainActivity. If I were to collapse the two ViewModels into one which is shared the list of items would persist in the MainActivityViewModel, even when not needed, correct? It would be a member variable of the MainActivityViewModel. I guess I could just make it null after one is selected. Does that sound right?

Comment: again, I think that you should consider whether that information should be global and is used from different places. If I were you, I would make a listener to pass that selected item back to the activity, just my opinion

Comment: It is used throughout the application. I created a GlobalSettingRepository which is a wrapper for SharedPreferences and that's how I've been pulling the data from everywhere I need it. Is this a better approach? Listener vs MutableLiveData, right?

Comment: SharedPreference is used for data which is persistent even when your app close. If it is your use case, that's fine!

Comment: have you resolved your problem. If so, and if my comment is useful for you, please give it an upvote. I really appreciate that and happy that it could help you